# error FATAL EXCEPTION : main

Tags: android, camera

i want to start camera with name from database and i have three database..
i have code like this:

```
public void startCamera() 
{
    long tim=System.currentTimeMillis();
     SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm:ss");
     String curTime =df.format(tim);
     System.out.println("Time : " + curTime);

    Cursor c = helper.getKomp(almagId2);
    Cursor ca = helper.getSat(almagId);
    Cursor cb = helper.getUlok(almagId1);
    if(c.moveToFirst()){
        fileName =c.getString(1)+"_"+"kanan"+"_"+System.currentTimeMillis()+ ".jpg";
    }else if(ca.moveToFirst()){
        fileName =ca.getString(1)+"_"+"kanan"+"_"+System.currentTimeMillis()+ ".jpg";
    }else if(cb.moveToFirst()){
        fileName =cb.getString(1)+"_"+"kanan"+"_"+System.currentTimeMillis()+ ".jpg";
    }

    _path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/DCIM/Camera/";


    file = new File(_path, fileName);
    try {
    file.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }               
    System.out.println(file);
    Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
    startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    if(c.moveToFirst()){
        db.execSQL("insert into image (kdstore,image1,tgl_buat) values ('"+c.getString(1)+"','"+file+"','"+curTime+"')");
    }else if(ca.moveToFirst()){
        db.execSQL("insert into image (kdstore,image1,tgl_buat) values ('"+ca.getString(1)+"','"+file+"','"+curTime+"')");
    }else if(cb.moveToFirst()){
        db.execSQL("insert into image (kdstore,image1,tgl_buat) values ('"+cb.getString(1)+"','"+file+"','"+curTime+"')");
    }
    db.close();


}
```

but when i want to call method startCamera i get error like this:

```
04-24 09:29:34.902: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9411): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-24 09:29:34.902: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9411): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-24 09:29:34.902: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9411):     at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:168)
04-24 09:29:34.902: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9411):     at com.sat.alfaloc.Camera.startCamera1(Camera.java:153)
04-24 09:29:34.902: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9411):     at com.sat.alfaloc.Camera.onClick(Camera.java:319)
04-24 09:29:34.902: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9411):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
04-24 09:29:34.902: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9411):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
04-24 09:29:34.902: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9411):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-24 09:29:34.902: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9411):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-24 09:29:34.902: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9411):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-24 09:29:34.902: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9411):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-24 09:29:34.902: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9411):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-24 09:29:34.902: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9411):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-24 09:29:34.902: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9411):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-24 09:29:34.902: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9411):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-24 09:29:34.902: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9411):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

how i can solved this??thank you for feed back :)

code above edited like this:

```
public void startCamera1() 
{
    long tim=System.currentTimeMillis();
     SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm:ss");
     String curTime =df.format(tim);
     System.out.println("Time : " + curTime);
     SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor c = helper.getKomp(almagId2);
    Cursor ca = helper.getSat(almagId);
    Cursor cb = helper.getUlok(almagId1);
    if(c.moveToFirst()){
        fileName =c.getString(1)+"_"+"kiri"+"_"+System.currentTimeMillis()+ ".jpg";
        _path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/DCIM/Camera/";
        file = new File(_path, fileName);
        try {
        file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(file);

        Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_CAPTURE1);
        db.execSQL("insert into image (kdstore,image1,tgl_buat) values ('"+c.getString(1)+"','"+file+"','"+curTime+"')");
    }
    if(ca.moveToFirst()){
        fileName =ca.getString(1)+"_"+"kiri"+"_"+System.currentTimeMillis()+ ".jpg";
        file = new File(_path, fileName);
        try {
        file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(file);

        Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_CAPTURE1);
        db.execSQL("insert into image (kdstore,image1,tgl_buat) values ('"+ca.getString(1)+"','"+file+"','"+curTime+"')");
    }
    if(cb.moveToFirst()){
        fileName =cb.getString(1)+"_"+"kiri"+"_"+System.currentTimeMillis()+ ".jpg";
        file = new File(_path, fileName);
        try {
        file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(file);

        Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_CAPTURE1);
        db.execSQL("insert into image (kdstore,image1,tgl_buat) values ('"+cb.getString(1)+"','"+file+"','"+curTime+"')");
    }

    db.close();

}
```

this is no error but activity call doesn't work..how solve it??thank you :)

Comment: remove this line System.out.println(file);

Comment: @Agarwal i try to remove but still error..error in this line `file = new File(_path, fileName);`

Comment: @Agarwal's comment doesn't make any sense -- ignore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception says that one of the arguments to the `File` constructor is null. It can't be `path_` because that would have led to a previous exception. It must be `filename_`. Your three-way if-else allows for the possibility that *none* of the branches will be true, and if none were, then `filename_` would be null -- so that must be what's happening. Can you have a default filename if none of the conditions are true -- i.e., can you add an `else` without an `if`, at the end of the chain?

Comment: i edit my code like above..no have error but camera activity doesn't start..how i solve it??thank you :)

Comment: This isn't surprising; we already suspected that each of the `if` conditions evaluated to false. Now you're made it so the code doesn't run at all if this is the case... so now it doesn't run at all. It looks like all your `Cursor`s are empty. Go back and look at those `helper` methods and figure out if something is wrong with your queries.

Comment: yes,,i try to manipulate my query And it's work!!thank you!!:)

Comment: yes,,i try to manipulate my query and it's work!!thank you!!:)